# Why can't I change sql_mode permanently?

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-5.6, sql-mode

I an currently using mysql server 5.6 in windows 10. while using mysql, an error keeps appearing that goes as something like this "the following column does not have a default value" i read on the internet that i can solve this problem if i change the sql_mode. It is currently set to

```
 sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I took this from "my-default.ini" file in "mysql server 5.6" folder. I read several other answers that say that if you want to permanently change your sql_mode, you should do it through the "my-default.ini" file. So what i did was, i run my notepad as administrator, then i browsed to open "my-default.ini" file that is found in:

```
  c:\programs files (x86)\mysql\mysql server 5.6\my-default.ini
```

when i opened the file, i modified the last line:

```
  sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

to

```
  sql_mode=
```

then i saved the file, closed it. then by using task manager i restarted  my sql sever:

```
  task manager >> services >> mysql56
```

This is the whole process that should permanently modify my sql_mode. when i look in my "my-default.ini" file, the last line is still modified. but if i log into mysql through the command line and view my sql_mode with the following code:

```
  select @@sql_mode;
```

I get that my sql_mode is

```
  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I want all this to be removed (permanently) in order for my error to disappear. IF i try to modify the sql_mode from the command line by using:

```
  set @@global.sql_mode="";
```

It worked, but when i restarted MySQL, everything was back as it was before.

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? and if there is another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Sorry, forgot you were using Windows 10. I'm not sure how to deal with this issue in Windows but maybe try copying `my-default.ini` to `my.ini` and changing that setting. Sorry for confusion.

---

Not sure if you can set your sql_mode to nothing but try changing the value in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. If that folder/file doesn't exist, create it and try setting `sql_mode` under `[mysqld]` like this:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=
```

I just did this same thing only I set the `sql_mode` to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: Your solution works for Linux too. It will need you to issue the command `service mysql restart` . If it does not restart, you know something didn't work. Also, I put this ine at the end for the file incase that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL Workbench installed, check the Server Status for the base directory of your instance. You should find a my.ini file there that keeps your changes.

Answer (score 0):

sql_mode need to add to file /etc/init.d/mysql as a argument to start like:

```
$bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" --sql-mode="" $other_args >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Restart MySQL database server to apply new config.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL 8 and ubuntu server 20.xx  I had to add:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTIO
```

To file
`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

In order that the setting stay persistent after server restart

**Disclaimer**:

this was the only place it actually worked, I have no idea what's the good practice where to add these custom settings but it 'ain't stupid if it works'. Somebody can tell me.

I tried the other options I found on forums:

- **my.cnf** did not work creating
- **custom cnf** did not work
- adding it to  **mysql.cnf** did not work